# Пересечение кликов на элемент REACT JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как обойти пересечение кликов(событий) в REACT.

1. RoomItem - родительский элемент
2. RoomItemHeader - дочерний элемент

На эти 2 элемента стоят разные события, но если я кликну по дочернему, то сработает только родительский. Нужно чтобы на каждый элемент срабатывало свое событие

```
<RoomItem onClick={method}>

<RoomItemHeader onClick={method2}>
   header
</RoomItemHeader>

</RoomItem>
```

Comment: Эм... значит выделение компонента было не правильным. Нужно из родительского выделить компонент и положить его рядом с вашим `RoomItemHeader`, рядом не в чаилд компонентс. Просто так выходит, что вы всегда кликаете по родителю, так как он более верхнего уровня и перекрывает дочерние.

Answer (score 0):

Помогло убрать вложение и сделать position: absolute;

```
<Room style={{position: 'relative'}}>

   <RoomItemHeader onClick={method2} style={{position: 'absolute'}}>
     header
   </RoomItemHeader>

   <RoomItem >
      item
   </RoomItem>

</Room>
```